# Create Project through Asana API

Tags: asana

Perusing through [the documentation](http://developer.asana.com/documentation/#projects), I see an endpoint that can be used to update existing Projects, but nothing about creating new Projects. Is this capability not currently supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I work at Asana)

This is indeed supported, though apparently specific mention is missing from the docs. Thanks for asking, we should correct this.

Comment: The Asana API docs now explain how to create a project via the API.

Comment: Is  it possible to give array of project names to create multiple projects in single create_project() call??

Comment: No, you must make a separate API call for each object you want to create.